# JAX-RS / jersey @Path parameter with regex for first character with ':' not working correctly

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a rest api which will accept path parameter for address value, below is the declaration

full URL: `http://localhost:8080/Myapp/client/2344/addresses/{address}`

```
@GET
@Path("/{address:.+}")
```

http://localhost:8080/Myapp/client/2344/addresses/**23/234-mainRoad** ->works

http://localhost:8080/Myapp/client/2344/addresses/**23:/234-mainRoad** ->works

http://localhost:8080/Myapp/client/2344/addresses/**:23/234-mainRoad**->not working value coming to server as **/234-mainRoad**.

If I encode the value then i am getting 400 error where its not hitting my service method.
http://localhost:8080/Myapp/client/2344/addresses/**%3A23%2F234-mainRoad**

I see this behavior is happening for some set of special characters only.what is the change do i need to make to accept all the characters irrespective of the position of the special characters

Comment: `:23/234-mainRoad` works here with Jersey 2.23. What Jersey version are you using?

Comment: i am using  jersey V1.17.1